# Homology Groups are Abelian Groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am talking about singular homology here.
I can recall that a chain complex is sequence of groups $C_n$ along with maps $f_n: C_n \to C_{n-1}$ where $f_{n+1}f_n=0$ or in other words $im(f_{n+1}) \subset ker(f_n)$

Now given a Topological Space $X$. We define a **singular-p-simplex** to be a continuous map from $\sigma_p \to X$. Here $\sigma_p$ is $p-simplex$ which is defined to be the convex hull of $\{e_1, e_2, \dots e_{p+1} \}\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$.

Next we define $C_n=S_n$ to be the 'free' group generated by all $n-$ simplices. Since this is a free group then $S_n$ is not abelian. Further we have the map $\delta:S_n\to S_{n-1}$ to be the map $\delta(f)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} d_i(f)$ . This forms a chain complex.

Then we define the homology gr)/oup of $X$ to be $\frac{ker{(\delta_n)}}{im(\delta_{n+1})}$. However I don't see why $H^n(X)$ always turns out to be abelian group?

> Further how can I find spaces with given homology groups?

Comment: oh, so only $H^0$ is abelian. Can you give some example where the homology groups of a space isn't abelian?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken because I confused with another homology theory. The point here is that it is a free abelian group, not a free group. Thus it is abelian by construction.

Comment: In the definition of [singular homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology), $C_n$ is not the free group generated by..., but the *[free abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group)* generated by... As for your final question, you should post it separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Next we define $C_n=S_n$ to be the 'free' group generated by all $n-$ simplices. Since this is a free group then $S_n$ is not abelian.

No, this is incorrect. We define them as [**free abelian**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) groups. Meaning the direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, one for each simplex. And so it is abelian by definition.

The boundary maps don't work well over just free groups. In particular I don't think $f_{n+1}f_n=0$ holds. Moreover you wouldn't be able to form a quotient, because in non-abelian case $ker f_n$ doesn't have to be normal in $im f_{n+1}$.

> Further how can I find spaces with given homology groups?

This isn't easy in general. Read about [Moore spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(algebraic_topology)).

Comment: can you explain me what is the difference between free group generated by $a,b$ and free abelian group generated by $a,b$. Is it that the free abelian group is quotiented by the commutator subgroup? That is does free abelian group mean $\frac{ a  b }{ \langle aba^{-1} b^(-1} \rangle}$ ?

Comment: @permutation_matrix the difference is precisely that in the first one $ab\neq ba$ while in the second one $ab=ba$. And in fact the free abelian group can be defined as abelianization (quotient by commutator) of free group. Typically though we just think about it as some $\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}$. Google and read about both on wiki.

Comment: But doesn't a free group mean there is no relationship between the generators?

Comment: @permutation_matrix yes. But we don't deal with free groups here. Whoever told you that, he made a mistake.

Comment: There are free objects in many different algebraic categories. The "no relationships between generators" interpretation is really only valid in the setting of (arbitrary, not-necessarily-abelian) groups.

Comment: When the context is very clearly restricted to ***abelian*** groups --- such as a discussion of chain complexes, cochain complexes, homology groups, etc. --- then the phrase *free group* is sometimes used as an abbreviation for *free abelian groups*, it being understood that all the groups are abelian anyway. As said in the comment of @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, this can be formalized with a bit of category theory.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing your 'free' groups. $C_n$ is the free **abelian** group, not the free group, generated by all $n$-simplices. A free abelian group on a set of generators $I$ is just the group $\bigoplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}i$, its elements are simply formal integral linear combinations of the generators. As a consequence, homology groups are abelian as quotients of abelian groups.